# Get id of a form belong to div containing active class

Tags: jquery

Lets say I have two divs

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade">
    <form id="own-connection"></form>
</div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade active in">
    <form id="inherited-connection"></form>
</div>
```

All I want is get id of child form whichever div have active as class. how could i do that? consider above two div as tab and when i click one of them active is get added as class.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

1) Chaining of class selector to get element with class `tab-pane` and `tabpanel`

2) `.Find()` selector to find form element

3) `.attr()` to get attribute ID

```
 $('.tab-pane.active').find('form').attr('id')
```

Comment: `tabpanel` is not a class name, why did you use it like `.tabpanel` ?

Comment: @Shafizadeh: Thanks for pointing. I was referring to `tab-pane`

Answer (score 0):

check the below code,

```js
$(function(){
var active_id=$(".tab-pane.active").find("form").attr("id");
console.log("active_form_id :"+active_id);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade">
    <form id="own-connection"></form>
</div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade active in">
    <form id="inherited-connection"></form>
</div>
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
function getID(){
let $id = $(".tab-pane.active").children().attr('id');
-----------------------------------^ case like this children much better than find cause find will search thru entire dom but children only 1 lvl down
return $id;
}
usage: getID() --> will return active class children id
```